# Fit and rotate two 3D mesh nodes in parallel

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, blender, cocos3d

I'm trying to fit the human skeleton completely **inside** the human body then rotate both meshes, but I'm not getting the result expected. I need your help.

The human integument 3D model was obtained from MakeHuman, I then bought a different 3D human skeleton from elsewhere to fit it inside the human integument model.  The skeleton model is significantly larger than the integument model, so I used Blender to **scale down** the skeleton. Within Blender, the skeleton fit nicely inside the integument.

My problems start when I integrate those two models into iOS.
First problem: As both the skeleton and integument models loaded, the skeleton mesh node still appear **much bigger** than the human integument although it was already scaled down via Blender.  I had to scale it down again using Cocos3D's `uniformScale` property in order to fit it inside the integument model. Note that both mesh nodes are position at the exact location distance from the camera.

Second problem: As I rotate both mesh nodes, the skeleton mesh node began surfacing and bleed through the integument mesh node. Both has the exact same rotation vector and same origin.

Help is much needed and appreciated.

Comment: Does anyone has any suggestion for this problem? Would adding constraints between skeleton and integument mesh nodes via Blender solve this problem?

Comment: I've noticed scaling the model in Blender has no effect on Cocos3D.

Comment: Have you tried making one model a child node of the other in Cocos3D?. You can then position/rotate/scale the child model to match the parent, and when you rotate the parent, the child will automatically rotate in sync with it.

Comment: Thanks Bill. That I have not and will do. So it seems setup done in Blender (position, scale, rotate, constraints...) will not be packaged in the pod file. Either that or Cocos3D doesn't interpret/decode those setup done in Blender?

Comment: The POD file does contain position, rotation, and scale properties for each node, and that info is read by Cocos3D (otherwise the various nodes within the model wouldn't align correctly relative to each other). When you load a model in Cocos3D, the contents of the POD file are logged, so you can dig into that if you want to see the properties of each component (node, material, etc). However, what I'm not an expert on is how Blender and the exporter extract the info you're looking for to get it into the POD file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Bill Hollings, this problem is solved by adding the skeleton as the child node of the integument model.